# Time as a value to compare against my value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How can I display time as a number value for an if statement?

I'm trying to write an if statement where a set time is compared against my computed time for an event to occur. I just don't know how to write that time as a value. how can I write a time like 10am as a set time value for example.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the NSDate class and the `timeIntervalSinceDate:` method to compare the two times. You need to set up the two NSDate objects with the different times (and the same date) and then call that method to compare the two.

Comment: They don't need to be on the same date.

Comment: Well that makes using NSDate even more useful. Parse the two dates (set date and computed date) into NSDate Objects and then use the timeIntervalSinceDate: method to compare the computed date to the set date object or vice versa

Comment: Apologies, thought you were the original poster and were saying that they won't be the same date and was asking a question. My bad :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is probably to convert the time to a UNIX timestamp (unsigned integer representing the number of seconds which have elapsed since january 1st 1970)

convert both times to this format and compare.

```
time_t unixTime = (time_t) [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
```

Comment: That's not the easiest way.  For a start you do not need to convert to time_t - `NSTimeInterval` is a double and can be compared directly to other `NSTimeIntervals` (from the same reference date).  Secondly, `NSDate` already has a method to do the compare (see Suhail's answer).

Answer (score 0):

To compare two dates use:

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(NSDate *)anotherDate
```

Here is the definition of NSComparisonResult:

```
enum {
   NSOrderedAscending = -1,
   NSOrderedSame,
   NSOrderedDescending
};
typedef NSInteger NSComparisonResult;
```